# C++ including a ".h" file, function duplication confusion

Tags: c++, function, include, header-files

I'm currently writing a program, and couldn't figure out why I got an error (note: I already fixed it, I'm curious about WHY the error was there and what this implies about including .h files).

Basically, my program was structured as follows:

The current file I'm working with, I'll call `Current.cc` (which is an implementation of `Current.h`).

`Current.cc` included a header file, named `CalledByCurrent.h` (which has an associated implementation called `CalledByCurrent.cc`).  `CalledByCurrent.h` contains a class definition.

There was a non-class function defined in `CalledByCurrent.cc` called `thisFunction()`.  `thisFunction()` was not declared in `CalledByCurrent.h` since it was not actually a member function of the class (just a little helper function).  In `Current.cc`, I needed to use this function, so I just redefined `thisFunction()` at the top of `Current.cc`.  However, when I did this, I got an error saying that the function was duplicated.  Why is this, when `myFunction()` wasn't even declared in `CalledByCurrent.h`?

Thus, I just removed the function from `Current.cc`, now assuming that `Current.cc` had access to `thisFunction()` from `CalledByCurrent.cc`.  However, when I did this, I found that `Current.cc` did not know what function I was talking about.  What the heck?  I then copied the function definition for `thisFunction()` to the top of my `CalledByCurrent.h` file and this resolved the problem.  Could you help me understand this behavior?  Particularly, why would it think there was a duplicate, yet it didn't know how to use the original?

p.s - I apologize for how confusing this post is.  Please let me know if there's anything I can clear up.

Comment: A good idea to simplify your post would be to post small sample files showing the contents of `Current.cc`, `CalledByCurrent.cc` and its respective headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have two global functions with the same name (even in 2 different translation units). To avoid getting the linker error define the function as `static` so that it is not visible outside the translation unit.

**EDIT**

You can use the function in the other `.cpp` file by using `extern` keyword. See this example:

```
//Test.cpp

void myfunc()
{

}

//Main.cpp
extern void myfunc();
int main()
{
    myfunc();
}
```

It will call `myfunc()` defined in `test.cpp`.

Comment: [Neil Butterworth's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027371/c-including-a-h-file-function-duplication-confusion/6027412#6027412) has an example of this.

Comment: Thank you.  So I understand why there would be a duplicate error.  What I don't understand is why when I remove the duplicate from Current.cc, I'm unable to use thisFunction() (despite the fact that redeclaring it caused a duplicate error).

Comment: @Casey P: You can use `extern` to achieve that. See the edit.

Comment: `extern` is not actually necessary, as functions have `extern` linkage by default.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting multiple definitions from the linker - it sees two functions with the same name and complains. For example:

```
// a.cpp
void f() {}

// b.cpp
void f() {}
```

then

```
g++ a.cpp b.cpp
```

gives:

```
C:\Users\neilb\Temp\ccZU9pkv.o:b.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `f()'
```

The way round this is to either put the definition in only one .cpp file, or to declare one or both of the functions as static:

```
// b.cpp
static void f() {}
```

Comment: But why does it see two functions with the same name when myFunction() is only included in the CalledByCurrent.cc and not in the .h?  Further, why when I remove the duplicate from Current.cc is it not able to use the function from CalledByCurrent.cc?

Comment: @The C Man Because resolving names across files is what the linker does.

Comment: So the linker just checks the names but not actually the usability?  So the linker might see it as a duplicate, despite the fact that Current.cc can't actually use that function?

Comment: Well, it can use it, by adding a declaration. But yes, the linker just checks names.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I liked your response a lot (and am giving you a thumbs up), but I've gotta give my answer pick to Asha.  His/her response was ideal because of the explanation of "global functions".

Answer (score 1):

The header file inclusion mechanism should be tolerant  to duplicate header file inclusions.

Comment: thats true, but the error described above is not related to multiple header inclusions.

Answer (score 1):

That's because whenever you simply declare a function it's considered in `extern` (global) scope (whether you declare it in a header file or not). Linker will have multiple implementation for the same function signature.

If those functions are truely helper functions then, declare them as;

```
static void thisFunction();
```

Other way, if you are using the same function as helper then, simply declare it in a common header file, say:

```
//CalledByCurrent.h  (is included in both .cc files)
void thisFunction();
```

And **implement thisFunction() in either of the .cc files**. This should solve the problem properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas:

- You didn't put a [header include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your header file.  If it's being included twice, you might get this sort of error.
- The function's prototype (at the top) doesn't match its signature 100%.
- You put the *body* of the function in the header file.
- You have two functions of the same signature in two different source files, but they aren't marked `static`.

---

If you are using gcc (you didn't say what compiler you're using), you can use the `-E` switch to view the preprocessor output.  This includes expanding all `#define`s and including all `#include`s.

Each time something is expanded, it tells you what file and line it was in.  Using this you can see where `thisFunction()` is defined.

Comment: even without header guard this error occurs. You can try writing an empty function inside 2 different cpp files and compile them together.

Comment: That's right.  I'll edit my answer to reflect this other possibility

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 distinct errors coming from 2 different phases of the build.

In the first case where you have a duplicate, the COMPILER is happy, but the LINKER is complaining because when it picks up all the function definitions across the different source files it notices 2 are named the same. As the other answers state, you can use the static keyword or use a common definition.

In the second case where you see your function not declared in this scope, its because the COMPILER is complaining because each file needs to know about what functions it can use.

Compiling happens before Linking, so the COMPILER cannot know ahead of time whether or not the LINKER will find a matching function, thats why you use declarations to notify the COMPILER that a definition will be found by the LINKER later on.

As you can see, your 2 errors are not contradictory, they are the result of 2 separate processes in the build that have a particular order.